# webbrowser_DocumentCompleted event stoppped working

Tags: vb.net

we have a code in windows application(developed in vb.net) that uses navigate method to access a webpage.

sample code is attached below for reference.
wbexplorer.Navigate("http://www.google.com/")

also we have Private Sub wbexplorer_DocumentCompleted event which was expected to trigger after the navigation step is complete.

This was working for years and suddenly this stopped working in few machines.

I am suspecting this could be related to patches that was deployed in my manchine however could not identify any thing on that front.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Sravan

Comment: Can you try [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) and tell us if the problem is still there?

Comment: Welcome to SO. `sample code is attached below`: I don't see any code. Could you edit your question, post a MVCE (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ). And give a bit more context, as such, pretty hard to guess.

Comment: @Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ-I tried the code however the behavior is still the same.Any suggestions.

Comment: @kebs- sample code is as below under form1_load event we are calling webbrowser.navigate method wbexplorer.Navigate"http://www.google.com/") and under wbexplorer_DocumentCompleted event we are using the code for authentication.The issue  here is it is never going to wbexplorer_DocumentCompleted event.